# Semaphores and Deadlock in java

Tags: java, operating-system

I am trying to learn about semaphores and deadlocks and I stumbled upon this. Can anyone give me a hint? anything. Thanks.

The methods threadA() and threadB() from the code below are launched in two separted threads. Is there any sequence of instructions leading to a deadlock? If yes, give one.

```
class ClassOne {
    static Semaphore lock1 = new Semaphore (1);
    static Semaphore lock2 = new Semaphore (1);

    void treadA(){
       lock1.acquire();
       //critical section
       lock1.release();
    }

    void threadB(){
       lock1.acquire();
       lock2.acquire();
       //critical section
       lock2.release();
       lock1.release();
    }
}
```

Same question for the second code:

```
class ClassTwo {
    static Semaphore lock1 = new Semaphore(1); 
    static Semaphore lock2 = new Semaphore(1);

    void threadA(){
        lock1 . acquire (); 
        lock2 . acquire ();
        //critical section
        lock2 . release (); 
        lock1 . release ();
    }

    void threadB() { 
        lock2 . acquire (); 
        lock1 . acquire ();
        //critical section 
        lock1 . release (); 
        lock2 . release ();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you already experienced a deadlock with this code, or are you expecting a code review?

Comment: Probably expecting a homework answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sample, no. No deadlock is possible.
In the second, yes:

1. `threadA` acquires `lock1` and then the VM yields control to `threadB`.
2. `threadB` acquires `lock2`.
3. Done!

In a situation like this, the easiest way to avoid interlocks is to assign a seguential number to every lock (you already did this by naming them `lock1` and `lock2`); and then code the threads so that they always acquire the locks in ascending order. To be more precise, no thread tries to acquire a lock if it owns a higher-numbered lock (in your second example, just reverse the `acquire` calls in `threadB`).

If, for some reason, a thread requires acquiring `lock2` at a much earlier time than `lock1` (so that it's not practical to keep ownership of `lock1` for a long time when it's not really needed), there are a few strategies that *probably* will help:

- renumber the locks so the order is convenient for the threads.
- when the thread needs to acquire `lock1`, first release `lock2`, then acquire `lock1`, then acquire `lock2` again.

With this strategy, no interlock is possible. To prove this, pick the highest-numbered lock which is not free (i.e. it's owned by a thread). The thread that owns this lock can always proceed, as it does not require any lower-numbered lock and all higher-numbered ones are free.

Comment: why is the first code part not producing a deadlock since both threads acquire the same lock?

Comment: They acquire it at different times. One thread can wait until the other releases the lock. A deadlock condition happens when _all_ threads are waiting for other (or the same, in some rare cases) thread.

Comment: so basically in the second part of the code lock1 and lock2 are waiting for each other to release. but that does not happen since they are both waiting for the other one.

Comment: Yes. That's it exactly.

Comment: And let's say I'm adding a third thread. Can the third thread release both locks although it did not acquire them? And implicitly solve the deadlock?

Comment: No way. A lock can be released _only_ by the thread that owns it (i.e. the one which acquired it). Of course, the OS (i.e. a privileged thread) can release locks, kill processes and do all kind of evil things, but "normal operation" is that whoever acquired the lock _owns_ the lock.
Edit: if locks could be happily released, acquiring a lock would make no sense, as the thread which acquired it could no longer trust that it has not been acquired by anyone else, which is the whole goal of having locks.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock happens when there is a possibility of getting locks in opposite sequence in different threads. As you can see in your second example, locks are taken in opp seq in diff threads, so there is a possibility of deadlock there. However in first example, lock(s) are taken in same sequence, so it won't deadlock

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet seems wrong as you have multiple locks but you do not take them in the same order in every place. You may experience the following deadlock:

```
   threadA aquires lock1
   threadB aquires lock2
   threadA block on lock2
   threadB locks on lock1
  => deadlock
```

You may find quite a lot or referring articles on it as it is a well know source of deadlock in multi-threaded context (whatever the language you use); You can have a look to this one https://books.google.fr/books?id=2hYqeoO8t8IC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score -1):

Cheeky Hudds Uni student trying to get a free pass through their Operating Systems assignment ;)

Comment: what? no. I asked a friend of mine if he could give me something to think about Deadlocks and Semaphores since I am trying to understand them as I said in the first post! I am not even at Uni. Cheers!